# Problem using data objects passed into JBPM 7.44/RH PAM 7.9 from

Tags: java, json, jackson, jbpm

I am having a lot of difficulty passing objects into JBPM 7.44; I have my own REST service that passes a map of parameters using the client API but the when a data object is passed - even when defined in Business Central - I get:

```
11:18:44,628 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (default task-34) Failed to define class module-info in Module "org.eclipse.yasson" version 1.0.5.redhat-00001 from local module loader @61ce23ac (finder: local module finder @3668d4 (roots: C:\jboss-eap-7.3\modules,C:\jboss-eap-7.3\modules\system\layers\base)): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link module-info (Module "org.eclipse.yasson" version 1.0.5.redhat-00001 from local module loader @61ce23ac (finder: local module finder @3668d4 (roots: C:\jboss-eap-7.3\modules,C:\jboss-eap-7.3\modules\system\layers\base))): module-info is not a class because access_flag ACC_MODULE is set
```

I have tried declaring AmsUser as both a data object in BC and as an imported class in a JAR.  Based upon warning about Jackson in the logs and my using RestEasy I have set

```
<property name="resteasy.preferJacksonOverJsonB" value="false"/>
```

When defined in an external JAR I get

```
10:33:57,841 WARN  [org.drools.persistence.PersistableRunner] (default task-28) Could not commit session: org.jbpm.workflow.instance.WorkflowRuntimeException: [DocumentSigner:20,665 - Setp Up:3] -- java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to AmsUser
        at deployment.kie-server.war//org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.executeAction(NodeInstanceImpl.java:239)
```

And these are some most of the Jackson and marshalling warnings in the logs:

```
2021-02-10 08:37:12,783 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry jsr173_1.0_api.jar in /C:/jboss-eap-7.3/bin/content/RestJbpm.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.4.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
2021-02-10 08:37:12,783 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry jaxb1-impl.jar in /C:/jboss-eap-7.3/bin/content/RestJbpm.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.4.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
2021-02-10 08:37:32,297 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in /C:/jboss-eap-7.3/standalone/deployments/business-central.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-core-2.3.0.redhat-1.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
2021-02-10 08:37:32,297 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry jaxb-core.jar in /C:/jboss-eap-7.3/standalone/deployments/business-central.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.3.0.redhat-1.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
2021-02-10 08:37:56,441 WARN  [ErraiMarshalling] (MSC service thread 1-1) static marshallers were not found.
2021-02-10 08:37:56,441 WARN  [ErraiMarshalling] (MSC service thread 1-1) using dynamic marshallers. dynamic marshallers are designed for development mode testing, and ideally should not be used in production. *
```

This seems like a pretty common issue: what do I need to change to pass an instance of "Ams" in my java.util.Map of parameters to the process I am starting via

```
processServicesClient.startProcess(containerId, workFlowId, correlationKey, map);
```

Please note that I have moved from Java 8 to Java 9 to try to directly address the module-info issue, but with no module definition I believe all the packages should have been exported (anonymously).  Please note that passing strings to the process in the java.util.Map works, so I am starting to write a trivial Java "ServiceTask" to parse a String into an AmsInstance (but am stuck on the module-info. I welcome all advice!

Comment: JBPM is not supported for JDK 9 btw, try with JDK 11